# Force Nginx to use browser port on redirect instead of docker mapping port

Tags: nginx, docker

When I map Nginx server with different ports on host and guest the location redirect follows guests port instead of the port from requested uri.

Step to reproduce:

```
$ cat /tmp/default.conf
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    location ~ ^/loveslash$ {
        return  301 $request_uri/;
    }
    location ~ ^/loveslash/$ {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 'yayy!';
    }
    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 '¯\_(ツ)_/¯';
    }
}

$ docker run --name some-nginx -v /tmp/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -p 80:8080 --rm nginx


$ curl -i http://localhost/loveslash | grep Location
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   169  100   169    0     0   165k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  165k
Location: http://localhost:8080/loveslash/
```

- What I get: `http://localhost/loveslash -> http://localhost:8080/loveslash/`
- What I want: `http://localhost/loveslash -> http://localhost/loveslash/`

Comment: Try adding `port_in_redirect off;` to the `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith it works. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'd add your suggestion as an answer, so "kudos" can be given ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using default ports, you can instruct Nginx to simply remove the port number from the URL when it generates an external redirect.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    port_in_redirect off;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect) for details.

Comment: It seems this doesn't work if your host port is different than the default `80` - it simply removes the port from the URL